# Making it so the user cannot press the button unless something is entered in the textfield

Tags: swift

How would I make it so a button that uses the segue to send you to the next view controller not work if nothing is entered in the text field above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add   this to the viewdidload, replacing textfieldVerb with the name of your textbox, and nextVerbOutlet with the name of your button (as a outlet)

```
self.textFieldVerb.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
        self.textFieldVerb.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
        nextVerbOutlet.enabled = false
```

and then add this replacing textfieldVerb with the name of your textbox, and nextVerbOutlet with the name of your button (as a outlet). This doesn't go in the viewdidload, but under it.

```
func textFieldChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    // simple validation
    if textFieldVerb.text?.characters.count > 0
        && textFieldVerb.text?.characters.count > 0 {
            self.nextVerbOutlet.enabled = true // re-enable your button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` of the `UITextFieldDelegate`. It will get triggered every time user enters or deletes character in the text field. You can examine the contents there and enable/disable your button from there appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the content of the TextField:

```
if myTF.text != "" || myTF.text != nil {
    //TextField contains something
    //enable button
    //segue to next ViewController
} else {
    //TextField empty
    //disable button
}
```

If you implement that into `textFieldDidEndEditing()` it will check each time the user is done typing.

Make sure to include the `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class like:

```
class myClass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {...}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and set your VC as the delegate.

Then implement the 
`func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)` 
method of that protocol.

You use this method to detect an empty string. You can choose to be thorough and handle copy/paste in which case you will need to calculate the value of the new string after the replacement using `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`, or you can choose to not handle copy paste and just check that `range.location > 0`.

Based upon the the above you can set the `enabled` property of the button accordingly.